# Where do I need to set my P3P header to bypass IE8 blocking cookies?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, p3p

I'm including a javascript file on my page that has a Set-Cookie header.  However, the cookie is being blocked by IE8.

Where do I set my P3P response header to prevent IE8 from blocking the cookie, on the javascript file request or on my web page?

Comment: What server side language and web server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup a test case, and it appears that the P3P response header needs to be received from the javascript request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below code to your login page action/servlet java file or place where the first response come.

`response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");`

Please let me know if it is not working .